# How to restart Chrome Remote Desktop from command line

Tags: chrome-remote-desktop

Say I was using Chrome Remote Desktop and remotely killed the host process on accident, causing me to get kicked off. However I still have SSH/terminal/command-line access. How can I relaunch the service so I can connect again?

Also, is it possible to install or reinstall Chrome Remote Desktop via SSH?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Restarting the service

**Linux**: The host process is a normal Linux service, so you can restart it by typing this in your SSH session:

```
sudo service chrome-remote-desktop restart
```

You should only have to wait a few seconds before it's ready for you to try connecting.

**Windows**, run these commands to restart the service (thanks @JohnLock):

```
net stop chromoting
net start chromoting
```

**macOS**:

```
launchctl start org.chromium.chromoting
```

### Reinstalling the service

(I don't know how to install/reinstall Chrome Remote Desktop via SSH. Someone please update this answer if you know how.)

Comment: Thanks for this! I have a machine whose Chrome Remote Desktop "server" (daemon) seems to "break" after a period of time. I used the following cron job to restart the daemon every hour which allows me to connect to the machine at any time: `0 * * * * service chrome-remote-desktop restart`

Comment: `sudo` seems to be optional (for me, at least).

Comment: Failed to restart chrome-remote-desktop.service: Unit chrome-remote-desktop.service is masked

Comment: hi @johndpope could you solve the "chrome-remote-desktop.service is masked" problem?

Comment: can't remember - I think I just yielded to remotedesktop.google.com / but that's not working for me these days.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows:

```
    net stop chromoting
    net start chromoting
```

Comment: Could you add some further context to this answer? Please see [answer] and take our [tour].

Comment: Thanks JohnLock. Welcome to StackOverflow!  I updated the community answer (: